# I cannot suddenly open ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

What is happening?

I have tried all suggestions from Stackflow concerning similar problems. I removed and reinstalled both rlang and ggplot2 and I have even reinstalled the whole R-studio on my computer.

I still got this message when tryin to open ggplot2: library(ggplot2).

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
namespace ‘ellipsis’ 0.3.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.3.2 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 4.0.5

Please can someone help me to solve this?

/Pia

Comment: as the warnings suggest, you want to try and reinstall `ellipsis`, something like `install.packages("ellipsis")`

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the problem this morning. What I did was remove all problematic packages and then reinstalling them. Sometimes need restarting R Studio before can reinstall a package

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29856134)

Comment: In my case it is not just reinstalling package "ellipsis", but several other packages were also required to be reinstalled. Hence, I suggest to remove and reinstall all required packages suggested by RStudio